# Forward slashes in powershell xml

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a large xml file that I'm trying to get some data from. There's a section in the XML I'm trying to get to:

```
<ContentItem>
<Variant variantCulture="en-US">
  <Field name="NavigationListItem/Filter/0/#Name" type="String">my bill</Field>
  <Field name="NavigationListItem/Filter/1/#Name" type="String">Trending topics</Field>
  <Field name="NavigationListItem/Filter/2/#Name" type="String">Manage Payment Options</Field>
  <Field name="NavigationListItem/Filter/0/Key" type="String">my bill</Field>
  <Field name="NavigationListItem/Filter/0/Title" type="String">my bill</Field>
  <Field name="NavigationListItem/Filter/0/Description" type="String"></Field>
  <Field name="NavigationListItem/Filter/1/Key" type="String">Trending topics</Field>
  <Field name="NavigationListItem/Filter/1/Title" type="String">Trending topics</Field>
  <Field name="NavigationListItem/Filter/1/Description" type="String"></Field>
  <Field name="NavigationListItem/Filter/2/Key" type="String">Manage Payment Options</Field>
  <Field name="NavigationListItem/Filter/2/Title" type="String">Manage Payment Options</Field>
  <Field name="NavigationListItem/Filter/2/Description" type="String"></Field>
```

My code so far is below. This repeats for several variantCultures. So far with my code I can loop through all the variantCultures and print all the fields (there's more than just the snippet I gave). I want to be able to print out something like this at the end:

Filter Name
Filter Key
Filter Description

For all filters. I'm just having trouble trying to select the field names with /'s in them.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\rasuser\Desktop\import\bill.xml | 
% { 
    $file = [xml](Get-Content $_.fullname)

    $path = $file.ExportedContentItem.path
    $name = $file.ExportedContentItem.name
    $GUID = $file.ExportedContentItem.ID


    $file.ExportedContentItem.ContentItem.Variant | % { 
        $locale = $_.variantCulture         

        $_.Field
    }       

    $out = $path + "/" + $name + "`t" + $GUID

    $out >> ".\outputee.txt"
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? What exactly do you mean you are having trouble trying to select the field names? Are you trying to get the #Name, Key, Title, and Description for each filter broken down and grouped or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, using just the snippet that you gave us as example saved into an XML file, let me know if this is what you're looking for...

```
$Filters = @()
$file = [xml](Get-Content C:\Users\rasuser\Desktop\import\bill.xml)

    $file.ContentItem.Variant | % { 
        $_.Field|%{$CurrentFilter = [pscustomobject]@{Value=$_.'#Text';Filter=$_.name.Split("/")[2];Key=$_.name.Split("/")[3]}
        $Filters+=$CurrentFilter
        }
        $Groups=@()
        $filters|Group-Object Filter|%{
            $CurrentGroup = [PSCustomObject]@{Filter=$_.Group.Filter[0]}
            $_.Group|%{Add-Member -InputObject $CurrentGroup -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Key -Value $_.Value}
            $Groups+=$CurrentGroup
        }
    }       
    $groups|ft
}
```